# Sort day/month array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an Array of dates from latest to oldest, and unfortunately list.sort (by default) only sorts the first number. My array looks like this:

```
var MyArray = ["13 Jun", "09 Jun", "25 Aug", "30 Jun", "13 Aug"];
```

I tried to make a function for the .sort to reference, but the whole process is somewhat confusing to me. Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to parse the strings into *Date()* objects, which would be straightforward enough if it weren't for IE's poor implementation of date string parsing.  Fortunately, you can use *setDate()* and *setMonth()* with consistency across browsers, both accept numbers - 1-31 for *setDate()*, 0-11 for *setMonth()*.  Setting up an object map for the month names will help.

This works for me:

```
(function () { 
    // Set up our variables, 2 date objects and a map of month names/numbers
    var ad = new Date();
    var bd = new Date();
    var months = {
        Jan: 0,
        Feb: 1,
        Mar: 2,
        Apr: 3,
        May: 4,
        Jun: 5,
        Jul: 6, 
        Aug: 7,
        Sep: 8,
        Oct: 9,
        Nov: 10,
        Dec: 11
    };

    MyArray.sort(function (a,b) {
        // Split the text into [ date, month ]
        var as = a.split(' '),
            bs = b.split(' ');

        // Set the Date() objects to the dates of the items
        ad.setDate(as[0]);
        ad.setMonth(months[as[1]]);
        bd.setDate(bs[0]);
        bd.setMonth(months[bs[1]]);

        /* A math operation converts a Date object to a number, so 
           it's enough to just return date1 - date2 */
        return ad - bd;
    });
})();
//-> ["09 Jun", "13 Jun", "30 Jun", "13 Aug", "25 Aug"]
```

I've set up an example for you - http://jsfiddle.net/Tw6xt/

Answer (score 2):

You would have to pass a sorting function to the sort method and define a date parsing function that creates an ordered representation of the date like so:

```
var MyArray = ["13 Jun", "09 Jun", "25 Aug", "30 Jun", "13 Aug"];
MyArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    a = parseDate(a);
    b = parseDate(b);
    if (a < b) {
            return 1;
    } else if (a > b) {
            return -1;
    } else {
            return 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to sort to do custom sorting:

```
function sortDate (a,b) {
    var aa = a.split(' ');
    var bb = b.split(' ');
    var months = {
        Jan : 1,
        Feb : 2,
        Mar : 3 /* you do the rest ... */
    }

    if (months[a[1]] > months[b[1]]) return 1;
    if (months[a[1]] < months[b[1]]) return -1;

    return parseInt(a[0],10) - parseInt(b[0],10);
}

MyArray.sort(sortDate);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution that doesn't reply on any constants.

```
var MyArray = ["13 Jun", "09 Jun", "25 Aug", "30 Jun", "13 Aug"];
var DateArray = [];
var SortedArray = [];
var dateBits;
for (var index = 0; index < MyArray.length; index++) {
 DateArray.push(new Date(MyArray[index] + " 2000"));
}
SortedArray = DateArray.sort();
MyArray = [];
for (var index = 0; index < SortedArray.length; index++) {
  dateBits = SortedArray[0].toDateString().substr(4, 6).split(" ");
  MyArray[index] = dateBits[1] + " " + dateBits[0];
}
```