# Javascript Customised Sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
months = ['Apr','Jan','Jul','Jun']
values = ['2','4','10','1']
```

How do I sort them not alphabetically but customized like below so the sorted arrays should be:

```
sMonths = ['Jan','Apr','Jun','Jul']
sValues = ['4','2','1','10']
```

I am guessing it should be done by map method? I checked here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

But I couldn't really understand how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine months and values into one array, sort it, and then extract months and values back.

```js
allMonths = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

months = ['Apr','Jan','Nov','Jun']
values = ['2','4','10','1']

combined = months.map(function(m, i) {
  return [allMonths.indexOf(m), m, values[i]];
}).sort(function(x, y) {
  return x[0] - y[0]
});

sMonths = combined.map(function(x) { return x[1] });
sValues = combined.map(function(x) { return x[2] });

document.write(JSON.stringify(sMonths) + "<br>");
document.write(JSON.stringify(sValues) + "<br>");
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the type of an answer I was looking for!

Comment: nicely done. I was confused at the question but the answer cleared the question for me.

Comment: This is not going to work in all cases, say you will sort "Nov" before "Apr". This is because you are trying to sort `combined`, which is an array of array. The way `sort` does it is to do a `toString()` on each of the sub-arrays and sort them as strings. You have to write a custom sort function to make it work.

Comment: @AlanTam Thank you so much, I was getting this bug and trying to figure out why it was happening!

Answer (score -1):

you should better store month as id (1->12) and at the end translate them into month names, but Andy E response fill your needs on [Sort day/month array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552189/sort-day-month-array-in-javascript)

```
(function () { 
    // Set up our variables, 2 date objects and a map of month names/numbers
    var ad = new Date(),
        bd = new Date(),
        months = {
            Jan: 0, Feb: 1, Mar: 2, Apr: 3, May: 4, Jun: 5,
            Jul: 6, Aug: 7, Sep: 8, Oct: 9, Nov:10, Dec:12
        };

    MyArray.sort(function (a,b) {
        // Split the text into [ date, month ]
        var as = a.split(' '),
            bs = b.split(' ');

        // Set the Date() objects to the dates of the items
        ad.setDate(as[0]);
        ad.setMonth(months[as[1]]);
        bd.setDate(bs[0]);
        bd.setMonth(months[bs[1]]);

        /* A math operation converts a Date object to a number, so 
           it's enough to just return date1 - date2 */
        return ad - bd;
    });
})();
//-> ["09 Jun", "13 Jun", "30 Jun", "13 Aug", "25 Aug"]
```

Comment: Would do, but I will wait for a better way and thank you for the example code snippet.